# Close parent window on iframe button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe without ID (generated by third party). The iframe is embedded on a landing page. When the submit button on the iframe gets clicked, I would like the window or landing page to be closed because when the submit button is clicked, it will open a new tab.

```
function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementByTagName('iframe');
    var sbutton = document.getElementById("form_002b_ao_submit_href");
    iframe.sbutton.onclick = function() {
        window.unload();
    }
};
```

but it does not get triggered.

Comment: try document.getElementsByTagName.contentWindow.document.getElementById("submit_btn")

Comment: then it would be best to do sbutton.onclick = function() { iframe.remove(); }

Comment: Let me know if above works and I will add it as an answer :)

Comment: did you try "parent.unload();"?

Comment: you mean like this? sbutton = document.getElementsByTagName.contentWindow.document.getElementById("#form_002b_ao_submit_href");
sbutton.onclick = function() { iframe.remove(); }

Comment: added as an answer, comment on the answer to let me know any issues :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('iframe').remove();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a little text to accompany the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to close the main window after the submit button is clicked then you can do something like the following.

[Live Preview](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/yONqQb)

[Link to the test page that is loaded in the iframe](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/dMoqPL)

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="http://s.codepen.io/larryjoelane/debug/dMoqPL"></iframe>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//select the iframe element without an id
var submitButton = $("iframe").contents().find("#submit_button");

submitButton.on("click", function(event) {


  //if you need to prevent default actions(form submit for example)
  event.preventDefault();

  //close the window
  window.close();

  //debugging only
  //alert("iframe submit button click event fired");

});
```

Comment: the problem is the iframe don't have an ID

Comment: @JeVic i gathered that from your question, my JavaScript code doesn't rely on using an id at all I will remove the id from the frame element to prevent any confusion.

Comment: @JeVic I uncommented the event.preventDefault() code so it should work now in the live example for chrome and firefox.

Comment: @JeVic My live update stopped working, It may have something to do with  codepen and the iframe use. You will have to test it now on your own machine. Let me know if you if works or if you need any more help with it.